# cakephp: structure database data returns

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

a possible return of a DB query looks like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Question' => array(
            'id' => '737',
            'question' => 'what is 1x7?',
        ),
        'Answer' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2373',
                'question_id' => '737',
                'correct' => true,
                'answer' => 'possible answer1',
                'created' => '2014-05-08 13:46:43',
                'modified' => '2014-05-08 13:46:43'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '2374',
                'question_id' => '737',
                'correct' => false,
                'answer' => 'possible answer2',
                'created' => '2014-05-08 13:46:43',
                'modified' => '2014-05-08 13:46:43'
            )
        ),
        'Linkquestioncategory' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '608',
                'question_id' => '737',
                'category_id' => '5',
                'created' => '2014-05-08 13:46:47',
                'modified' => '2014-05-08 13:46:47',
                'Category' => array(
                    'id' => '5',
                    'name' => 'Simple Math',
                    'active' => true,
                    'linkquestioncategory_count' => '64',
                    'created' => '2014-02-03 09:20:54',
                    'modified' => '2014-03-04 14:47:05'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

In order to clean it up to avoid sending to much unwanted data => my questions is => how can I get rid of those fields like

- Answer.created
- Linkquestioncategory.created
- Linkquestioncategory.Category.created

I know that I can use conditions 'fields' to select the selected fields, but as far as I know, this works only for 'Question', but how can I manipulate those deeper array data?
Can I do this also with the 'fields' condition? If yes, how?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to show your existing find call, the short answer is "containable". Please **tag your question with the version of CakePHP you are using**.

Comment: use containable behavior in models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/05/example-of-cakephps-containable-for-deep-model-bindings/

This helped me a lot!!
Thanks!!

Comment: This is a terrible answer, but if it's "the" answer please accept it.